# Use igraph in C++ projects

Tags: c++, eclipse, igraph

I have tried to install igraph by running the following commands (as described in the manual):

./configure
 make
 make check
 make install

The installation instructions do not provide any further information where to go from here however. How do use the files in my ongoing projects (for instance in Eclipse)?

According to the manual, the installation process is adding files to the 'usr/local/bin', but this folder is empty after the installation (no hidden files).

What would be the easiest way to use the files in my C++ projects?

Answer (score 0):

The installation process is adding include files in `/usr/local/include` (more precisely in `/usr/local/include/igraph` only) and library files in `/usr/local/lib`. Stick `/usr/local/include` to your include path in Eclipse, add `/usr/local/lib` to your library path in Eclipse, and add `igraph` to the list of linked libraries, and you are good to go. Make sure to use `#include <igraph/whatever.h>` in your C++ code to include igraph-specific stuff.

Also, [this project](https://github.com/ntamas/igraphpp) tries to provide a more C++-like API for igraph. It is still experimental, the API changes all the time and many igraph functions are not wrapped in C++ equivalents yet, but it's a starting point that you can extend.

Comment: Thank you for your answer Tamas. However, somehow the installatoin process did not add any files to the include and lib folders you mentioned. Can I manually add them, or is there a way to check what went wrong during hte installation?

Comment: Run `make install` and find any error messages in the output.

Comment: So as described in the installation instructions I started with:
./configure
which produces the following errors:
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lxml2
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lz
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: When running 'make check' and 'make install', I get the same error. Is the reason for this error that I am running the commands from within the download folder? Should change to usr/local/include. Or is it maybe because I do not have root rights?

Comment: When I run 'make installcheck', I receive the error message that:
ERROR: All 234 tests were run,
234 failed unexpectedly.
It also produces a testsuide.log file (which I can provide if necessary), which has in every test the same error message mentioned above.

Comment: I did checked for a /usr/bin/ld folder and no such folder exists. Is this some package that is required for igraph, and if so, can I install it somehow?

Comment: You are missing the `libxml2` and `libz` libraries (well, most likely the development files of these libraries), both of which are dependencies of igraph. If you are running Ubuntu or Debian Linux, install `libxml2-dev` and/or `libz-dev` first before trying to compile igraph.

Comment: So after installing libxml2 and libz libraries, the installation finally worked. Thank you so much!!!

Comment: I was able to run the example from the igraph tutorial in a new cpp file from the command line. When building this file, I had to provide the location of the library files. I copied the same commands into the make file that I am using within Eclipse, which worked fine.

Comment: However, in order to run the program, I needed to provide the address of the libraries again (so "LD_PRELOAD=/usr/local/lib/libigraph.so ./igraph_test"), which worked just fine from the command line. But when I add those exaxt same lines to my arguments in the run configuration, I receive this error:
[proxy:0:0@m2108] HYDU_create_process (./utils/launch/launch.c:69): execvp error on file LD_PRELOAD=/usr/local/lib/libigraph.so (No such file or directory)

Comment: It appears that instead of adding LD_Preload to my Run arguments in Eclipse, I need to add it to my Environment in there. I am not exactly sure, however how to add this line in there.

Comment: So in environment, I just added LD_Preload as a variable, and the absolute path as a value, and now it finally runs. Thanks again!!!

Comment: I guess you are running some Linux variant. In most Linux distributions, you can adjust the path where the linker looks for dynamic libraries in `/etc/ld.so.conf` or `/etc/ld.so.conf.d` so the best course of action is probably to add `/usr/local/lib` to the linker path permanently (because this is fairly common in some Linux distributions anyway). Please refer to the documentation of your Linux distribution on how to do it.

Comment: You are correct, I am using Ubuntu. So I checked the file 'libc.conf' in /etc/ld.so.conf.d and it already contains the line: /usr/local/lib. Maybe I need to add '/usr/local/lib/libigraph.so' instead. 
I will peruse the Ubuntu documentation and see if I can find anything.

Comment: No need to add `/usr/local/lib/libigraph.so`. You probably need to run `ldconfig`; check this answer as well: http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/67784

Comment: Yes, you are right, ldconfig did the trick (I had to reboot in between though, not sure why exactly, but now it works). Thanks again so much!!!